# How to receive broadcast packets with Indy10 TIdUDPClient?

Tags: delphi, udp, c++builder, indy10

I'm connecting to a system that sends UDP packets, both as responses (sent to a specific IP address) and as broadcasts (dest 255.255.255.255, according to WireShark)

I can receive the 'direct' packets correctly, but I can't work out how to get the broadcast ones. I assume I need a second TIdUDPClient with different bindings, but I haven't been able to get it working.

```
TIdUDPClient *reader(new TIdUDPClient(NULL));
TIdUDPClient *broadcastReader(new TIdUDPClient(NULL));

reader->Port = 2000;
reader->Host = "192.168.0.1";
reader->Connect();

broadcastReader->Port = 2000;
// broadcastReader->Host = "0.0.0.0"; // This doesn't work, but is here as an example
broadcastReader->BroadcastEnabled = true;
broadcastReader->Connect();
```

I then have other near-identical threads calling `reader/broadcastReader->ReceiveBuffer()`. The `reader` one works fine, but `broadcastReader->receiveBuffer()` never returns...

Apologies for C++ code and a Delphi tag ;-)

Comment: If the goal is to receive unsolicited packets, don't you need a *server* component rather than a *client*?

Comment: @RobKennedy - So it would seem - But, I'm only interested in receiving broadcasts from one particular host IP. The distinction between client and server with a connectionless protocol like UDP seems a little strange, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TIdUDPClient` is not designed for receiving broadcasts.  Use `TIdUDPServer` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I was heading to that conclusion. This does appears to have changed since Indy9, as I'm sure I was able to receive broadcasts with a UDPClient previously.

Comment: One other point - with a server, I'll normally receive broadcasts from ALL hosts sending on that port - can I automatically restrict that to a single host, or should I just inspect the sender of each packet?

Comment: It is not so much that `TIdUDPClient` cannot receive broadcasts at all. It is just that it cannot automate the receiving like `TIdUDPServer` does.  `TIdUDPServer` has an `OnUDPRead` event that is triggered whenever new data arrives. You would have to call one of the `TIdUDPClient.Receive...()` methods manually, such as in a timer or a thread, to accomplish the same thing. You really should not be using `Connect()` when handling broadcast data, though. `Connect()` establishes a static link between IP/Port pairs, so it might end up filtering your your broadcast packets at the OS layer.

Comment: I've switched from two(!) clients to one server, and let Indy manage the listening thread. It works fine, and my code is much simpler. Could have been the `connect()` that was the problem, but I'm happy with the new solution.

Comment: `TIdUDPServer` does not natively support any kind of filtering, so you would have to look at the sender IP manually on each packet. You might be able to set the `TIdSocketHandle.PeerIP` property of each `TIdUDPServer.Bindings` entry before activating the server, then use the `TIdUDPServer.OnAfterBind` event to call `TIdSocketHandle.Connect()` on each entry afterwards, but I don't know if that will actually work or not, I have never tried it.

Comment: And it would be a race condition since the `OnUDPRead` event updates the `TIdSocketHandle.PeerIP` property, so if data arrives from an unwanted peer before you can call `Connect()`, you might end up filtering for the wrong peer.

Comment: OK, I'm not calling Connect, and just inspecting the passed ABinding.PeerIP in OnUDPRead, which seems to work. But, is there one thread generated for each host that sends UDP packets on that port? And if so, how do I close down the threads I'm not interested in?

Comment: There is one thread for each entry in the `TIdUDPServer.Bindings` collection. If multiple peers are sending packets to the same IP/Port of your server, the packets will be serialized in the `OnUDPRead` event as only one thread will be reading them from the network one packet at a time.